# Django Rest: passing queryset to hyperlinked model serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

```
class JobViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.JobSerializer

    @action(methods=["get"], detail=True, url_path="like-detail", url_name="like-detail")
    def list_likes(self, request, pk=None):
        job = self.get_object()
        queryset = job.likes.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={"request": request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Error**:
AssertionError at /jobs/12/like-detail/
Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

Not sure how can i pass data arg because is have a queryset, i tried with .values() and .values_list() but that don't solve the purpose because then no hyperlink (url) will be available of UserSerializer.